# R: Calculating Cumulative Variances

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

- I am trying to write a simulation which shows the cumulative variance of a basketball being shot 100 times with success probability = 0.5 (i.e. variance of first n shots, first n+1 shots, first n+2 shots, etc.).
- This entire simulation is then repeated 100 times and then visualized.
- Note that the variance after the first shot is always 0

Here is my attempt at doing this:

```
n_shots <- 100
prob_success <- 0.5
n_simulations <- 100

cumulative_variances <- matrix(nrow = n_shots, ncol = n_simulations)


set.seed(123)  
for (i in 1:n_simulations) {

  shots <- rbinom(n_shots, 1, prob_success)
  

  cumulative_variances[,i] <- sapply(1:n_shots, function(j) if(j > 1) var(shots[1:j]) else 0)
}


plot(1:n_shots, cumulative_variances[,1], type = "l", ylim = range(cumulative_variances),
     xlab = "Shot Number", ylab = "Cumulative Variance",
     main = "Cumulative Variance of Basketball Shots Across Simulations")
for (i in 2:n_simulations) {
  lines(1:n_shots, cumulative_variances[,i])
}


abline(h = 0.25, col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]

**Can someone please tell me if this is correct?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks right to me. This is relatively easy to vectorize with the formula for the variance of Bernoulli observations:

```
shots <- matrix(rbinom(n_shots*n_simulations, 1, prob_success), n_shots)
cum_shots <- as.matrix(cumsum(as.data.frame(shots)))
cumulative_variances <- cum_shots*(1:n_shots - cum_shots)/(1:n_shots)/(0:(n_shots - 1))
cumulative_variances[1,] <- 0
```

Here, each column in the `shots` matrix is a simulation replication.